# Active record has_many

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I need to list all user with their total product sold by them with their email and the product total quantity,

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # id, location_id, email
  has_many :orders, dependent: :destroy
end

class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
#status, payment_mode, total_cost, user_id
  has_many  :order_items, dependent: :destroy
  belongs_to :user
end

class OrderItem < ActiveRecord::Base
# order_id, product_id, quantity,total_price
  belongs_to :order
  belongs_to :product
end

User
id email
1  test@gmail.com
2  test2@gmail.com
```

Order
    id user_id
    1   1
    2   2

```
OrderItem
id order_id product_id  quantity 
1  1        1            5
2  1        2            5
2  2        3            5
```

I need to display like
    name             product_count
    test@gmail.com     10
    test1@gmail.com    5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this:

```
OrderItem.includes(:order => :user).group('users.email').sum(:quantity)
```